# multithreading database query VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, multithreading

I have a multithreading application which retrieves a value from a SQL database. While these multiple threads run, sometimes the return value from the database is the same for some threads causing my calculation to fail.

How to prevent this?

```
 TaskList = New ArrayList
  Private Sub Sample()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
            Dim Id, Width, Height As Integer
            Dim t As New Tasks.Task(Sub() Go(Id, Width, Height))
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub Go(Id As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer)
        Dim D As Decimal = 0
        D = CallWebService("MODEL", Width, Height, 1, "SOMETHING")
        UpdateDimensionsTable(Id, Width, Height, D)
        CalcResult(ProductId, RunId, Width, Height, D, 0)
    End Sub
```

inside the webservice call the value from the db is retrieved.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: You did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did (and tell us what you were trying to achieve) then we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Private Sub Sample()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
            Dim Id, Width, Height As Integer
            Dim t As New Tasks.Task(Sub() Go(Id, Width, Height))
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub Go(Id As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer)
        Dim D As Decimal = CallWebService("MODEL", Width, Height, 1, "SOMETHING")
                    End Sub

Comment: Edit your question to include your code and be sure to format as code.

Comment: I can see an advantage to using async and await to call your web service and maybe do your calculations so the ui does not hang. The code you posted really does not look like it will run

Comment: Thats correct it wont work. just to give an Example. The task is added to the task list. Another sub is processing the task list and executes 8 tasks at a time. The sub runs until al tasks have status rantocompletion.

Comment: Fixed it my own by useing synclock